# Generating live resource class like R.java in android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, r.java-file

How can I generate a live resource class just like what android generates based on its layout xmls, R.java, based on my customized xml file?
Is there any specific plugin for android studio to actively watch for a particular xml file, namely mylayout.xml, and generate a java class, namely myR.java as I'm writing codes?

***EDIT:*** What I want to do is to create NON-VIEW objects from an xml file which defines objects and their attributes, but not in run-time. My intention is to auto-generate a before-run-time class which contains those objects ids and there would be such methods like getMyObject(int id) which automatically instantiate the object from its relevant class.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, could you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Android will automatically add the things from any custom XML layout to the `R` class. You do not need to do anything special for this, beyond coding your custom layout in line with Android's style and requirements. See [Creating Custom Views](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).